# Figure eight shaped head

Tags: story-identification, aliens, young-adult, horror

I'm desperately trying to find a book series I had gotten as a kid in the early-mid 90's. This is all that I can remember about them:

- The books were paperback, all with dark or black covers
- Most likely young adult horror
- There are illustrations at the back of the monsters/aliens in the book. One I remember has an eight shaped head and is also described as such in the book
- There is also a monster that resembles a "Gremlin" (the ugly green version, not the cute cuddly version) and I think he/it is the host of the book series